# How To Test Whether a Set is Reflexive, Symmetric, Anti-Symmetric and/or Transitive?

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty trying to code these functions.  They are not working properly and do not know what I am doing wrong.  As for Transitive, I cannot even get started and would like any help you can give on it and what I am doing wrong in my functions.  Thank you.
Sample inputs:

```
0 1 2 3 //elements (A)
0 0     //relations (B)
1 1
2 2
3 3

x y z //elements (A)
x y   //relations (B)
y z
y y
z z

x y z //elements (A)
x x   //relations (B)
y z
x y
z y
x z
y y
z x
y x
z z

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 //elements (A)
1 4             //relations (B)
1 7
2 5
2 8
3 6
4 7
5 8
6 6
1 1
2 2
```

Code:

```
bool reflexive(int a[], int sizeOfA, int b[], int sizeOfB) 
{
  bool hold = true;
  for(int i=0; i+1<sizeOfB; i+=2) 
  {
    int e = b[i];
    int e1 = b[i];
    if(pair_is_in_relation(e1, e, b, sizeOfB) == false) 
    {
        if (hold) 
    {
            return false;
            break;
         }
    }
  }
  if (hold)
    cout << "Reflexive - Yes" << endl; 
  else
    cout << "Reflexive - No" << endl; 
return hold;
}

bool symmetric(int a[], int sizeOfA, int b[], int sizeOfB)
{
bool hold = true; // set hold to true
for(int i=0; i+1<sizeOfB; i+=2) // for each pair (e,f) in b
{
    int e = b[i];
    int f = b[i+1];
    if(is_in_relation(f, e, b, sizeOfB)) // if pair(e,f) is not in b
    {
        if(hold) // set hold to false
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if(hold) // if hold return true
    cout << "Symmetric - Yes" << endl;
else // if hold is false return false
    cout << "Symmetric - No" << endl;
}

void antiSymmetric(int b[], int sizeOfB)
{
bool hold = true; // set hold to true
for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfB;) // for each pair (e,f) in b
{
    if(hold == false)
    {
        cout << "AntiSymmetric - No" << endl; 
        break; //Did not find (e,e) in b
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeOfB;)
    {
        if(b[i] == b[j+1] && b[i+1] == b[j]) //If true, then pair(f,e) exists
        {
            if(b[i+1] != b[i]) //If true, relation is antisymmetric
            {
                hold = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                hold = false;
                j = j + 2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hold = false;
            j = j + 2;
        }

    }
    i = i + 2;

}
if(hold == true)
    cout << "AntiSymmetric - Yes" << endl;

}

void transitive(int a[], int sizeOfA, int b[], int sizeOfB)
{

}

int main()
{
char keepGoing = 'y';
    while (keepGoing=='y') {

int set1[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int rel1[8] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3};
cout << "Set 1: " << endl;
reflexive(set1, 3, rel1, 4);
symmetric(set1, 3, rel1, 4);
antiSymmetric(set1, 3, rel1, 4);

cout << endl;
char set2[4] = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
char rel2[8] = {'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z'};
cout << "Set 2: " << endl;
charReflexive(set2, 4, rel2, 8);
charSymmetric(set2, 4, rel2, 8);
charAntiSymmetric(set2, 4, rel2, 8);

cout << endl;
char set3[3] = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
char rel3[18] = {'x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y', 'x', 
                 'z', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'z'};
cout << "Set 3: " << endl;
charReflexive(set3, 3, rel3, 18);
charSymmetric(set3, 3, rel3, 18);
charAntiSymmetric(set3, 3, rel3, 18);

cout << endl;
int set4[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int rel4[20] = {1, 7, 2, 5, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 7, 5, 8, 6, 6, 1, 1,
                2, 2};
cout << "Set 4: " << endl;
reflexive(set4, 8, rel4, 20);
symmetric(set4, 8, rel4, 20);
antiSymmetric(set4, 8, rel4, 20);

cout << endl << "Would you like to test it again? (y/n): ";
    cin >> keepGoing;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific.  What doesn't work?  (i.e. what output do you expect, and what do you get?).  Have you tried running on a minimal dataset in the debugger?

Comment: `They are not working properly`.  What are they doing?  What did you expect them to do?

Comment: Also, I'm no expert in set theory, but I thought properties like "reflexive" etc. applied to *relations*, not sets?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Given that two sets are passed to the function, I would assume that the question really is "How to determine if a pair of sets representing a relation, ...".

Comment: @AndréCaron: This is beyond my level of maths, then!  What does it mean to ask "is a pair of sets representing a relation reflexive?"?

Comment: I don't know why it changed my formatting I am not by my computer I code with.  How does the reflexive look now?

Comment: @CraigAshworth: I've reformatted it, the problem is the interpretation of tabs, it's best to post code with only whitespace for indentation (and you should learn to use the `continue` keyword to limit the depth of indentation ;) )

Comment: @AndréCaron: Craig updated.  Apperently `a` holds set elements. Each two elements in `b` represents a relation.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth nothing. A pair of sets isn't a relation. A relation is a set of pairs. The terminology on this question and all of its answers are completely confused. The inputs are arrays not sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only read `reflexive`, but you need to rethink that.  In general, if the first element in `A` is not equal to the first element in `B`, it prints `"Reflexive - No"` and stops.  I don't think you thought that through all the way.

[EDIT] Alright, now that we've finally established what `int a[]` holds, and what `int b[]` holds, I have to start over.  What everyone had before was completely wrong.  (Me especially, my old "reflexive" was really symmetric, as well as interpreting the inputs wrong.)  If you've learned about C++ classes/containers, I would highly recommend replacing `int a[]` and `int b[]` with something like:

```
template <class T>
struct relation {
    typedef std::pair<T,T> single_relation;

    std::set<T> elements;
    std::set<single_relation> all_relations;
};
```

or something similar, but that's just me.

```
reflexive:
    set holds to true
    for each element e in a
        if pair(e,e) is not in b
            set holds to false
            break
symmetric:
    set holds to true
    for each pair(e,f) in b
        if pair(f,e) is not in b
            set holds to false
            break
antisymetric: 
    set holds to true
    for each pair(e,f) in b
        if pair(f,e) is in b
            if f is not e
                set holds to false
                break
transitive:
    set holds to true
    for each pair(e,f) in b
        for each pair(f,g) in b
            if pair(e,g) is not in b
                set holds to false
                break
        if holds is false
            break
```

Note that only reflexive actually requires `a[]` at all.
Demo:

```
bool pair_is_in_relation(int left, int right, int b[], int sizeOfB)
{
    for(int i=0; i+1<sizeOfB; i+=2) {
        if (b[i]==left && b[i+1]==right)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool antiSymmetric(int b[], int sizeOfB) 
{
    bool holds = true;
    for(int i=0; i+1<sizeOfB; i+=2) {
        int e = b[i];
        int f = b[i+1];
        if(pair_is_in_relation(f, e, b, sizeOfB)) {
            if (e != f) {
                holds = false;
                break;
             }
        }
    }
    if (holds)
        std::cout << "AntiSymmetric - Yes" << endl; 
    else
        std::cout << "AntiSymmetric - No" << endl; 
    return holds;
}
```

Comment: In none of his `for(int j` does he increment `j`. Not that it matters, he always `break`s out of it at the first iteration...

Comment: @Mooning Duck... i used your pseudo code but it is giving reflexive for all of my relations.  How can I post the function in the comment to show you? All I see is `code` but do not know how to use that here.  Thanks.

Comment: 1. (0,0),(1,1) - reflexive
2. (0,0),(1,1),(1,2) - not reflexive
3. (1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2) - reflexive

Comment: Every element is related to itself, i.e., a relation ~ on R where x~x holds true for every x in R.  How can I post the function in the comment?

Comment: @MooingDuck... It is still telling me all relations are reflexive to the set.  Please look above and see if I did this right. Thanks.

Comment: @CraigAshworth `if(a[j] = elemB)` assigns the value of `elemB` to the element at `a[j]`.  Use two equal signs to compare: `if(a[j] == elemB)`

Comment: @MooingDuck.. Thanks for catching that but still the same output. All say reflexive.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Now, its outputting none of them are reflexive.  I put my main in my code to see if I was doing something wrong there.

Comment: @MooingDuck: You used my main?  Am I creating my sets and relations correctly?  It should be coming out Set 1 and 3 are reflexive.  I keep getting none are reflexive.

Comment: @CraigAshworth: I did not use your main.  I'm looking at it now.  Why are A and B different sizes?  Earlier you said `(0,0),(1,1),(1,2) not reflexive`.  I took that to mean `A={0,1,1} B={0,1,2}`.  Is that wrong?  If so, what forms a pair in the relation?  As it is, none of those samples look reflexive.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  I was giving you examples of what reflexive meant.  Here are my inputs.  The top input is the set and the pairs under it are its relations.  I am testing to see if the relations are reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric and transitive.  I put it them up top.

Comment: @CraigAshworth: Everyone completely misunderstood what was in `a` and what in `b`.  A description of that in the original post would have made this easy to answer.  Anyway, answer replaced entirely.

Comment: @MooingDuck : Thank you so much for your patience.  Sorry I was unclear with what I was trying to do by not providing you with my inputs.  Just a quick question, what do you mean by saying (e,e), (e,f), (e,g) ect.  Are you saying a[i] == a[i], a[i] == b[j] ect?

Comment: I have not been over that yet.  How can I use that in my functions after I create that? Or will it still work without it?

Comment: @CraigAshworth: If you haven't learned classes, then forget that for now.  The `pairs(e,f)` in `{x,y,y,z,y,y,z,z}` are `x,y`, `y,z`, `y,y`, and `z,z`.  If the current `pair(e,f)` is `x,y`, then _it's_ `pair(f,e)` would be `y,x` (reversed elements. Not in `b`.). The `pairs(f,g)` would be `y,x`, `y,y`, and `y,z` (pairs whos first element is the same as the "current's" second element, but may or may not be in `b`.)

Comment: @MooingDuck : Wouldn't I need to use two for loops to loop through all the elements in b? How would you know if the pair is in b without looping through it?

Comment: @CraigAshworth: You will have to loop through to see if it is in b.  However, put that in a function `bool is_pair_in_relation(int left, int right, int b[], int sizeOfB)`.  It'll keep things easier.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I have my reflexive and symmetric functions working but seem to be having trouble with antisymmetric... I am receiving No for all of them but should be getting Yes for Set 2 and 4.  Do you see where I went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @CraigAshworth: Actually, they're all wrong.  The two states for `holds` are not `it is symetric` and `it is not symetric`, but are `it might be symetric` and `it is not symetric.`  99% of the time you should _not_ set `holds` to anything.  I added to my code to be more clear about that.

Comment: @MooingDuck : This is so frustrating... How else can I break out of the loop when hold = true after I find the relation?

Comment: @CraigAshworth: if the loop finishes without setting hold to false, then hold will be true.  You won't know it's true until you complete the _entire_ thing.  I put in the code for antisymetric.  Look how close it is to the psudocode I gave.  Then go fix the other functions.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I am working on the other functions now.  Just checking the antisymmetric function, it came back true for the set 1, 2, and 4, but set 1 is not antisymmetric.

Comment: @CraigAshworth: Sets 1, 2, and 4 are antisymetric.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I apologize I didn't know a relation could be both symmetric and anitsymmetric.  Also, do I create a new function for pair_is_in_relation for reflexive,symmetric and transitive?

Comment: @MooingDuck I tried creating a new function for symmetric is_is_relation and received Yes for set 1 but none of the other sets printed.  Is this right? I posted above.

Comment: @CraigAshworth: 1 is both symmetric and antisymmetric (Yeah, it's confusing).  You can use the same `pair_is_in_relation` for all of them.  1 is your only symmetric set.  But the `is_in_relation` says `b[i]!=left` which is wrong. The line in symmetric that is wrong is `if(is_in_relation(e, f, b, sizeOfB) == false) // if pair(e,f) is not in b`

Comment: @MooingDuck: Why is it not printing out my set 2 and set 4 for symmetric?  Iv'e been messing around with it but nothing will print.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Now I changed reflexive but it isn't printing out sets 2 or 4 either...

Comment: @CraigAshworth: Your reflexive does _not_ match my psudocode. Your reflexive is actually _close_ to testing symmetry.  I've given you waaay more help than I should have already.  I gave you non-C++ code for three parts, and gave you the C++ code for the other.  Seriously.  Go talk to your teacher.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, what's the purpouse of this `for` loop where you never increment the variable being iterated?

```
for(j = 0; j < sizeOfB;)
{
    ...
}
```

And why having such an overcomplicated `for` endless loop if you are breaking out of it at the first iteration?

If you need to iterate over the cross product of both sets, you could use the following code snippet as a start:

```
for( int i = 0; i < sizeOfA; ++i )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < sizeOfB; ++j )
    {
        int elemA = a[i];
        int elemB = b[j];

        ... do your magic ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @K-ballo... This is looping through multiple times printing it out more than once.  What am I doing wrong... I do not know how to post code into a comment so I edited my function above.

Comment: @K-ballo.. When your declaring elemB should it be b[j] not b[i]?

Comment: @Craig Ashworth: Your code needs quite some work just in order to get it to tell whether every element of A is also in B, and that's just a start. I would recommend you post a separate question on how to implement just `reflexive`, what does it mean (to you) and maybe some samples on expected output.

Comment: @Craig Ashwort: Indeed it should be `b[j]`. Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to get your terminology straight: A set S isn't reflexive, symmetric, transitive or anything of the sort. That is why you're having such a hard time visualizing what transitive(...) should do.

Only a **particular** binary relation B on a **particular** set S can be reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Now, let's think of this in terms of a set and a relation. Let's assume you have a function, conveniently called relation:

```
bool relation(int a, int b) 
{
    /* some code here that implements whatever 'relation' models. We will
     * pick some relation we know to be reflective, transitive and symmetric.
     * For example: 
     */
    return (a == b);
}
```

Let's add a bad relation too, just for fun. You can use it to test:

```
bool relation_bad(int a, int b) 
{
    /* some code here that implements whatever 'relation' models. This is
     * a relation that isn't symmetric, but it is reflexive and transitive. 
     */
    return (a >= b);
}
```

Now, you want to code up 'reflexive'. Reflexivity means that an item is related to itself:

```
bool reflexive(int *s, int items) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i != items; i++)
    {
        if(!relation(s[i], s[i]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And now, 'symmetric'. Symmetry means that if a is related to be, then b must be related to a:

```
bool symmetric(int *s, int items)
{
    for(int i = 0; i != items; i++)
    { // for every item in the set:
        for(int j = 0; j != items; j++)
        { // check against every other items (including itself!)
            if(relation(s[i], s[j]) != relation(s[j], s[i])
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I won't code transitive for you, but transitivity means that if a is related to b, and b is related to c, then a must be related to c.

You can see that you will need three loops and more complicated check here.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\to find symetric relation
#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;
main() {
    int a[5],b[5],c,d=0,e,f;
    cout<<"Enter 1st elemtnts: ";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    cout<<"Enter second elemnt :";
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        cin>>b[j];
    }
    for(c=0;c<5;c++){
        for(d=0;d<5;d++){
            if(a[c]==b[d]){
                cout<<"("<<a[c]<<",";
                cout<<b[d]<<")";
            }     
        }
    }   
    cout<<" Are the symetric \n\n";
    system("pause");
}
```