# How can I test whether a relation is transitive in Lua?

Tags: lua, relation

I need to make a program that will test whether a given relation is transitive.

I had an idea to use linked lists for this, but I don't know how. I have seen answers to similar questions, but none of them were for Lua and since I'm just learning to code, I don't know how to make those answers useful for me.

This is my current attempt at this:

```
relation={{1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1}}
n=3
for i=1,n do
if relation[i][1] == relation[i][2] then
print("transitive")
else if relation[i][1] ~= relation[i][2] then
print("checking")
for q=1,n do
_G["x"..i]=relation[q][1]
_G["y"..i]=relation[q][2]
end
if _G["x"..i] == nil then
print("transitive")
end
for w=1,3 do
if
_G["y"..i] == relation[w][1] then
relation[w][2] = z
for e=1,3 do
if 
z == relation[e][2] and e ~= w then
if relation[e][2] == _G["x"..i] then
print("transitive")
end
else print("not transitive")
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
print("end loop 1")
for i=n,1,-1 do
if relation[i][1] == relation[i][2] then
print("transitive")
else if relation[i][1] ~= relation[i][2] then
print("checking")
for q=n,1,-1 do
_G["x"..i]=relation[q][1]
_G["y"..i]=relation[q][2]
end
if _G["x"..i] == nil then
print("transitive")
end
for w=n,1,-1 do
if
_G["y"..i] == relation[w][1] then
relation[w][2] = z
for e=n,1,-1 do
if 
z == relation[e][2] and e ~= w then
if relation[e][2] == _G["x"..i] then
print("transitive")
end
else print("not transitive")
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide more information on your specific application? do you have code of your attempts in using a linked list for this problem? why do you believe a linked list is good solution? Can you include links to the other answers that you are unsure how to translate to lua?

Comment: I tried to use linked lists, but failed. An example of such answer that I don't know how to translate to Lua is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155850/how-to-test-whether-a-set-is-reflexive-symmetric-anti-symmetric-and-or-transit I have been working on some code, but I'm not even close to getting it done.

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked question is also code-only and it is difficult to understand what is asked for. Could you describe the algorithm you are trying to implement with words? It is not easy to understand  how un-formatted and non-idiomatic code works. It hard to say why is it not working. (Well, for the particular snippet I could make a guess, that it doesn't work because of the line `if for e=1,3`, but that probably won't help you with your actual problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got it to work! I don't know how, but it works and that's important!

```
relation={{1,2}, {2,1}, {2,2}}
n=3
for i=1,n do
if relation[i][1] == relation[i][2] then
print("transitive")
else if relation[i][1] ~= relation[i][2] then
print("checking")
for q=1,n do
_G["x"..i]=relation[i][1]
_G["y"..i]=relation[i][2]
end
if _G["x"..i] == nil then
print("transitive")
end
for w=1,3 do
if
_G["y"..i] == relation[w][1] and w ~= i then
relation[w][2] = z
for e=1,3 do
if 
z == relation[e][2] and e ~= w then
if relation[e][2] == _G["x"..i] then
print("transitive")
end
else print("not transitive")
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
print("end loop 1")
for i=n,1,-1 do
if relation[i][1] == relation[i][2] then
print("transitive")
else if relation[i][1] ~= relation[i][2] then
print("checking")
for q=n,1,-1 do
_G["x"..i]=relation[i][1]
_G["y"..i]=relation[i][2]
end
if _G["x"..i] == nil then
print("transitive")
end
for w=n,1,-1 do
if
_G["y"..i] == relation[w][1] and w ~= i then
relation[w][2] = z
for e=n,1,-1 do
if 
z == relation[e][2] and e ~= w then
if relation[e][2] == _G["x"..i] then
print("transitive")
end
else print("not transitive")
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
```